# How to cope with grouped together warning?

Tags: elixir

There are a couple of def groups, and when I write @spec, it's warned with `warning: clauses for the same def should be grouped together, def foo/2 was previously defined`. Is there any workaround for that?

Although the warning is useful, but I'd like get it to ignore @spec.

```
@spec foo(:id, integer) :: {:not_found} | {:ok, String.t}
def foo(:id, id) do
  # some logic
end

@spec foo(:email, String.t) :: {:not_found} | {:ok, String.t}
def foo(:email, email) do
  # some logic
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@spec foo(:id, integer) :: {:not_found} | {:ok, String.t}
@spec foo(:email, String.t) :: {:not_found} | {:ok, String.t}

def foo(:id, id) do
  # some logic
end

def foo(:email, email) do
  # some logic
end
```

or you could a single spec instead

```
@spec foo(:id | :email, integer | String.t) :: {:not_found} | {:ok, String.t}
```

I have not tested it but it should work.

Comment: Thank you. I took the former way, and it settled the warning.